# What kinds of things are stored in 1 byte files?

Tags: file, operating-system, filesystems, filesize

Page 301 of Tanenbaum's *Modern Operating Systems* contains the table below. It gives the file sizes on a 2005 commercial Web server. The chapter is on file systems, so these data points are meant to be similar to what you would see on a typical storage device.

| File length (bytes) | Percentage of files less than length |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6.67 |
| 2 | 7.67 |
| 4 | 8.33 |
| 8 | 11.30 |
| 16 | 11.46 |
| 32 | 12.33 |
| 64 | 26.10 |
| 128 | 28.49 |
| ... | ... |
| 1KB | 47.82 |
| ... | ... |
| 1 MB | 98.99 |
| ... | ... |
| 128 MB | 100 |

In the table, you will see that 6.67% of files on this server are 1 byte in length. What kinds of processes are creating 1 byte files? What kind of data would be stored in these files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't familiar with that table, but it piqued my interest. I'm not sure what the 1-byte files were at the time, but perhaps the 1-byte files of today can shed some light?

I searched for files of size 1 byte with

```bash
sudo find / -size 1c 2>/dev/null | while read line; do ls -lah $line; done
```

Looking at the contents of these files on my system, they contain a single character: a newline. This can be verified by running the file through hexdump. A file with a single newline can exist for multiple reasons, but it probably has to do with [the convention of terminating a line with a newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline).

There is a second type of file with size 1 byte: symbolic links where the target is a single character. ext4 appears to report the length of the target as the size of the symbolic link (at least for short-length targets).